# sample-Groceries\platforms\android\gradlew.bat failed with exit code

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

While trying to follow the tutorial on NativeScript.org for the sample groceries app for Android using a Dell Inspiron

```
OS: Windows 10 Home
Processor: AMD A8-7410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics 2.20 GHz
Installed memory (RAM): 8.00 GB (6.94 GB usable)
System type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
```

according to step 1.4 as seen here [http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1#11-install-nativescript-and-configure-your-environment](http://ppl-web.net/errors.txt) I get the following error(s) after executing the following command:

```
tns run android --emulator
```

Here is the exception:

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class android.support.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat$AnimatedVectorDrawableCompatState conflict: C:\_Sandbox\NativeScript\sample-Groceries\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\23.4.0\jars\classes.jar and C:\_Sandbox\NativeScript\sample-Groceries\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\23.3.0\jars\classes.jar
            at com.telerik.metadata.ClassRepo.cacheJarFile(ClassRepo.java:21)
            at com.telerik.metadata.Builder.build(Builder.java:39)
            at com.telerik.metadata.Generator.main(Generator.java:44)
    :buildMetadata FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':buildMetadata'.
    > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 1 mins 19.102 secs
    Command C:\_Sandbox\NativeScript\sample-Groceries\platforms\android\gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1
    # run android
```

I have also included the log file below:

(the file is too big, here is link)

[Error(s) Log File](http://ppl-web.net/errors.txt)

Comment: Have you run `tns doctor` command? is it showing everything is fine with the environment ?

Comment: TNS Doctor results

Comment: Yes, and I get the following output:

 Updates available
 
 │ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information      │
 │ nativescript     │ 2.0.1           │ 2.1.0          │ Update available │
 │ tns-core-modules │ 2.0.0           │ 2.1.0          │ Update available │
 │ tns-ios          │ 2.0.0           │ 2.1.0          │ Update available │
 
 No issues were detected.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart any update for me to try?

Comment: You could try to upgrade to latest NativeScript, following the steps here - https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions and to run `tns run android`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  To fix it, I installed Android 6.0 (API 23).

So.. go to the cmd prompt (Windows), enter 'android'.  It opens up the Android SDK Manager.  Find Android 6.0 and install it.

After that, the 'tns platform add android' command worked.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the version of the “Android Support Repository” you’re using. Run the Android SDK Manager, make sure “Android Support Repository” is checked, click “Install”, and then try again.

You can access the Android SDK Manager by typing `android` on your command line or terminal.

Comment: I tried the above but when looking I noticed the Android Support Repository checkbox was already checked.  So no luck here.